# Skype 5.5 - How do I clear the "username" field so that nothing is shown when I start Skype under Windows?

Tags: windows, skype, cache, username

For Skype 5.5 under Windows (Vista), every time I start the program the username is filled in. How do I get rid of this 'cache' such that it is completely empty every time I start the program? Or, at the very least, change its value to something more generic (to help preserve some privacy)?

Comment: Set a password on your Windows account.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this [link](http://skypefun.net/notrace.html) may help.

It states,

> Always, when you sign in Skype from some computer, your Skype name
>   stays forever in the Skype list menu. Sometimes it is not desirable to
>   be seen that you have been entering in Skype from that computer. To
>   remove your name , just make follow few steps:
>
> 1. Open a File Manager and in address field write %AppData%\Skype\  (so you may enter there manually – go to C:\Documents and Settings
>      \”current user name”\ Application Data\Skype ).
> 2. You are now in the folder that Skype save it`s system fails. There must be a folder with your Skype Name. If your Skype Name is Beauty23
>      , there must be a folder with name Beauty23.
> 3. Delete the folder, and you are ready. Delete only the folder that has such name as your Skype Name, if you delete something else , you
>      may damage Skype.

Comment: Please don't just post links like that, with absolutely no explanation. They are only helpful until the site goes down.